# Converting Enum between modules

Tags: c#, c, enums, module

I have an enum definition in one module(A), e.g. SUCCESS = 0, INVALID_REQ = 1 etc. Then I have another dll (module B) which has its own set of status enum. Once we add a new enum value in A, we have to manually add it to B since A is in .NET and B is C code. Beside, enum in A is only part of the status enum in B (B has its own internal status besides status from A). 
This seems a very tight coupling between these two modules. Any suggestions to make them less coupled?
Thx!

Comment: The biggest problem here isn't keeping the two in sync (though that is a problem), but rather the fact that the enum in B means something different than the enum in A.  Now you open up the possibility for wanting to add a new element to A, but suddenly it conflicts with an internal value being used by B.  If you need to duplicate values for the purpose of interoperability, use it _only_ for interoperability and manage internal state separately.

Comment: There is an *implicit contract* going on here. Imagine HTTP2 adds a new verb say, [JABBERWOCKY](http://www.jabberwocky.com/carroll/jabber/jabberwocky.html). All HTTP2 clients/servers would need to be encoded with knowledge of this contract. Using explicit [protocol] versions, perhaps with guards and [downward compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility), can be useful to catch and/or mitigate mismatches. There exists tooling to help with sharing contract information -- imagine [COM IDLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) or other scaffold-generators.

Comment: @Dan: I am thinking to use enum values in A as is and define const in B starting from 100 (0-99 from A). Then use integer instead of enum as B's interface. Both A and B's status can be exposed from B's interface and not to worry A and B interfere each other.

Answer (score 2):

Why not write a simple script that generates these enums based on a file during build? If you truly want to uncouple them, you will need to make someone a master and expose its content to the other side.. Likely using RCW..

Comment: :) That is not the end of the world to write.. :)

Answer (score 1):

What would be fun would be to use reflection here. Write a little program that reads the enum by reflection from module A, and generates a .h file for use in the c module.